# Magento 2 - Category url load very slow

Tags: magento2, php, admin, category, layout

I have a very strange problem in frontend when open a category after in the adminhtml change the Design Layout to 1 column. If the category have the Design Layout 2 columns-left for example everything is fine but after change to 1 column the loading speed is 2 minutes.
[image]
How I can debug to see exactly where is the problem? What is the best practice?

Thank you

Comment: Try new relic to monitor eventually ? I never used it though

Comment: I've also got this issue with Porto on first load. TTFB is painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally Category pages or any page will be slow if following not taken care of :

From TTFB perspective or server execution time.

1. Varnish or Full Page cache is used.
2. Also to make sure no block is set as cacheable = false or internal coding should not set cache to false.
3. If FPC is varnish is not an option then check the mysql query log with stack for the queries and model that are consuming resources.

from your question it appears that the issue is on TTFB so have not explained other web Vital parameter aspects.